# Как изменить кнопку отправки формы

Tags: css, css3

Что получается - [image: то, что у меня выходит]

Что нужно - [image: пример того, что мне нужно]
Конкретнее - мне нужно убрать белую кнопку и сделать так, что бы кнопкой стал весь овал.

```
    .login-submit {
      position: absolute;
      top: 120px;
      right: 140px;
      width: 120px;
      height: 30px;
      padding: 6px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.login-submit {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 92px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font: 38px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #eb8321;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="login-submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не именяет память, стилизовать input type="submit" плохая идея, так как safari на mobile берет стандартные стили.

```css
.login-submit {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font: 400 18px Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      background: #FF6501;
    }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="login-submit">Войти</button>
```